# How to save Multi part file image to Database using Web Service in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services

While doing image uploading using IOS and android i have ASP.net web service .The devices sending web service multi-part data for image.How to read multipart data in web service and save path to data base and save image to file system.Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage UpdateImage()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var filepath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filepath))
            {
                string ImageLocalPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadImage/" + file.FileName);
                file.SaveAs(ImageLocalPath);

                // write code for insert in the database and give ImageLocalPath  parameter in a stored procedure to store path, also create UploadImage folder to store image 
            }
        return HttpResponseData.OkResponse();
        }
    }
```